# JSF 2.1 - Facelet cache factory configuration

Tags: jsf

I am using Mojarra 2.1.2 and want to configure the facelet cache factory. I tried the following in my WEB-INF/faces-config.xml but it does not seem to work.

```
     <factory>

    <facelet_cache_factory>org.valuesource.custdb.web.extension.SimpleFaceletCacheFactory</facelet_cache_factory>
 </factory>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't use underscores. Use hyphens.

```xml
<facelet-cache-factory>
```

No one XML element of `faces-config.xml` uses underscores. Note that the [`FaceletCacheFactory`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/view/facelets/FaceletCacheFactory.html) was introduced in JSF 2.1, so ensure that your `faces-config.xml` root declaration conforms JSF 2.1:

```xml
<faces-config
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_1.xsd"
    version="2.1">
```

Comment: BalusC - I salute you. You are the best in JSF. That was really silly on my part.